# How to add a job to be started at a fixed time every day and to be finished at a fixed time with APScheduler

Tags: python, cron, apscheduler

I am currently doing data processing in python, but the amount of data I handle is so large that it takes an enormous amount of time.
I would like to run the data processing job every day between 6pm and 6am, and proceed gradually.

Is it possible to do that with APScheduler?

Comment: I've done some research and it seems that APScheduler alone can't quit at 6:00, maybe I should use sleep or something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

APScheduler can schedule the job to start, but your code needs to check the time on each iteration and return from the call if the hour is between 7 am and 5 pm.